# Bug Fixing: Copied images in Excel VBA appear as blank images

Tags: image, vba, excel, copy-paste

The program I have been writing reads information from various sources in the workbook, rearranges the information into several compact tables on separate sheets, and then copies those tables as images into a separate summary sheet. I have written this program as several different sub routines that are called on by the main program.

When the main program runs, the images it pastes into the summary sheet have the correct dimensions and placement, but they are completely white. However, when I run the sub routine responsible for copying those images over, it succeeds in actually copying the correct tables. Here is the code I am using to copy and past the tables, as images:

```
Sub ExtractToPresentation()

Call UnprotectAll

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Application.CutCopyMode = False

startcell = Worksheets("Supplier Comparison").Cells(1, 1).Address
bottomcell = Worksheets("Supplier Comparison").Cells(21, 14).Address

Set copyrng = Worksheets("Supplier Comparison").Range(startcell, bottomcell) '.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

copyrng.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap

With Worksheets("Presentation")

    .Paste _
        Destination:=.Range(SupSt)

End With
```

The sub routine continues, but the rest is a variation on the above code for each additional table:

```
startcell = Worksheets("Rating Criteria").Cells(1, 1).Address
bottomcell = Worksheets("Rating Criteria").Cells(12, 7).Address

Set copyrng = Worksheets("Rating Criteria").Range(startcell, bottomcell)
copyrng.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap

With Worksheets("Presentation")

    .Paste _
        Destination:=.Range(CritSt)

End With

startcell = Worksheets("Comments").Cells(1, 1).Address
bottomcell = Worksheets("Comments").Cells(4, 14).Address

Set copyrng = Worksheets("Comments").Range(startcell, bottomcell)

copyrng.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap

With Worksheets("Presentation")

    .Paste _
        Destination:=.Range(CommSt)

End With

startcell = Worksheets("Component Table").Cells(1, 1).Address
bottomcell = Worksheets("Component Table").Cells(CompH, CompW).Address

Set copyrng = Worksheets("Component Table").Range(startcell, bottomcell)

copyrng.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap

With Worksheets("Presentation")

    .Paste _
        Destination:=.Range(CompSt)

End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Call ProtectAll

End Sub
```

The variables ending in St, H, and W are defined in a previous program that determines the size of each table. I have no idea why this program functions perfectly on its own, but returns blank images when run after other programs.

Let me know if anyone wants to look at other parts of my code. There are ~500 lines in this program, and I didn't want to dump everything all at once.

Comment: What happens if you add `DoEvents` after the line `copyrng.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap`

Comment: The results do not change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Range(*source*).Copy                           ' full source range

' asume you have a destination cell as a range
*destination*.Parent.Select                    ' select sheet
*destination*.Select                           ' select dest cell
*destination*.Parent.Pictures.Paste            ' paste
```

If you need to resize the image, use

```
*sheet*.Shapes(x).Height
*sheet*.Shapes(x).Width
```

working example:

```
Sub Test()
    Set src = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1", "B4")
    Set dst = Sheets("Sheet2").[C5]
    src.Copy
    dst.Parent.Select
    dst.Select
    dst.Parent.Pictures.Paste
    src.Parent.Select
    src.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: This almost works, but the images are not pasting to the specific range I select. They all paste into cell A1.

Comment: right ... I was testing this on only one sheet ... just found out you need to select the dest cell in dest sheet before pasting ... code edited

Comment: Your updated code worked perfectly, thank you. Do you know why my original code was pasting in blank images?

Comment: Sorry ... I don't have the faintest idea :-( ... just recorded a macro to see what Excel would do, then compared with yours ... 't was different, purified the code and played around a bit

Answer (score 1):

Try `application.screenupdating = true` also `displayalert - true`, and see if it works.

I was having the same problem while copying object from excel to PPT, and when I made `screeupdating = true`(default), it started working :-)

Swarup

Answer (score 0):

I am inserting over 3.000 pics from several files and sometimes this problem appeared as well.
I could solve the problem by inserting a short break [ Sleep(25) ] followed by [ DoEvents ] right after the insertion and placement of the picture. 
No ScreenUpdating needed...